# GSheets Trigger for updating entries wont work - Script does work manually tho

Tags: google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I want to run a script for GSheets by a trigger every minute.
The script works without an error if I run it manually, but the trigger will throw an error message 100% of the time.
The idea is to populate a spreadsheet via GForms. The script should update the entries when a new form of an existing data set is submitted (identifier is in row 4). It does this by looking for duplicates and deleting the old set of data.
The trigger should run the script every minute or so to ensure data quality and to eliminate multiple duplicates if they occur.

This is the code for my script:

```
    function updateExisting(columnWithUniqueIdentifier,sheetTabName) {
  var dataFromColumnToMatch,lastColumn,lastRow,rowWithExistingUniqueValue,rowOfDataJustSaved,
      sh,ss,valueToSearchFor;

  // USER SETTINGS - if the values where not passed in to the function
  if (!columnWithUniqueIdentifier) {//If you are not passing in the column number
    columnWithUniqueIdentifier = 4;//Hard code column number if you want
  }

  if (!sheetTabName) {//The sheet tab name was not passed in to the function
    sheetTabName = "Formularantworten 2";//Hard code if needed
  }
  //end of user settings

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Get the active spreadsheet - this code must be in a project bound to spreadsheet
  sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetTabName);

  lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  lastColumn = sh.getLastColumn();

  Logger.log('lastRow: ' + lastRow)

  rowOfDataJustSaved = sh.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();//Get the values that were just saved

  valueToSearchFor = rowOfDataJustSaved[0][columnWithUniqueIdentifier-1];
  Logger.log('valueToSearchFor: ' + valueToSearchFor)

  dataFromColumnToMatch = sh.getRange(1, columnWithUniqueIdentifier, lastRow-1, 1).getValues();
  dataFromColumnToMatch = dataFromColumnToMatch.toString().split(",");
  Logger.log('dataFromColumnToMatch: ' + dataFromColumnToMatch)

  rowWithExistingUniqueValue = dataFromColumnToMatch.indexOf(valueToSearchFor);
  Logger.log('rowWithExistingUniqueValue: ' + rowWithExistingUniqueValue)

  if (rowWithExistingUniqueValue === -1) {//There is no existing data with the unique identifier
    return;
  }

  sh.getRange(rowWithExistingUniqueValue + 1, 1, 1, rowOfDataJustSaved[0].length).setValues(rowOfDataJustSaved);
  sh.deleteRow(lastRow);//delete the row that was at then end
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Updating Data Set Successful")
}
```

The Trigger will throw this Error Message:

23.11.2020, 10:27:03    Info    lastRow: 7

23.11.2020, 10:27:03    Info    valueToSearchFor: undefined

23.11.2020, 10:27:03    Fehler  Exception: Konvertierung von "[object Object]" in int nicht möglich.
at updateExisting(Code:28:30)

[GSheet_Trigger_Error_Messeage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b016.png)

Any idea of what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks so much in advance.

EDIT:
Here is a debugger log for rowofdatajustsaved & columnWithUniqueIdentifier.
Seems like they work as intended.

[Debugger_Log_UpdateExisting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ3aN.png)

Comment: Can you `Logger.log(rowOfDataJustSaved)` just after `rowOfDataJustSaved` is created?

Comment: is it possible that the trigger is calling the `updateExisting` function with a `columnWithUniqueIdentifier` that is invalid? Maybe log `columnWithUniqueIdentifier` at the beginning of the script to see what is happening there.

Comment: @iansedano thx for your reply! I run the debugger for the rowOfDataJustSaved and columnWithUniqueIdentifier  (pic of this above).
Only time these are not filled with data / invalid is during the var statement which should not be the problem, I think?

Comment: I mean logging it while is executes as a trigger, not manually.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: there has to be a trigger var in the var statement. I figured that there is an unnecessary if statement in the code as well and fixed it. Updated code below.

```
function updateExisting(trigger, columnWithUniqueIdentifier,sheetTabName) {
  var dataFromColumnToMatch,lastColumn,lastRow,rowWithExistingUniqueValue,rowOfDataJustSaved,
      sh,ss,valueToSearchFor;

  Logger.log('columnWithUniqueIdentifier' + columnWithUniqueIdentifier)
  // USER SETTINGS - if the values where not passed in to the function
  columnWithUniqueIdentifier = 4;//Hard code column number if you want
  
  Logger.log('sheetTabName' + sheetTabName)
  if (!sheetTabName) {//The sheet tab name was not passed in to the function
    sheetTabName = "Formularantworten 2";//Hard code if needed
  }
  //end of user settings
  

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Get the active spreadsheet - this code must be in a project bound to spreadsheet
  sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetTabName);

  lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
  lastColumn = sh.getLastColumn();

  Logger.log('lastRow: ' + lastRow)

  rowOfDataJustSaved = sh.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();//Get the values that were just saved
  Logger.log(rowOfDataJustSaved)
  debugger

  valueToSearchFor = rowOfDataJustSaved[0][columnWithUniqueIdentifier-1];
  Logger.log('valueToSearchFor: ' + valueToSearchFor)

  dataFromColumnToMatch = sh.getRange(1, columnWithUniqueIdentifier, lastRow-1, 1).getValues();
  dataFromColumnToMatch = dataFromColumnToMatch.toString().split(",");
  Logger.log('dataFromColumnToMatch: ' + dataFromColumnToMatch)

  rowWithExistingUniqueValue = dataFromColumnToMatch.indexOf(valueToSearchFor);
  Logger.log('rowWithExistingUniqueValue: ' + rowWithExistingUniqueValue)

  if (rowWithExistingUniqueValue === -1) {//There is no existing data with the unique identifier
    return;
  }

  sh.getRange(rowWithExistingUniqueValue + 1, 1, 1, rowOfDataJustSaved[0].length).setValues(rowOfDataJustSaved);
  sh.deleteRow(lastRow);//delete the row that was at then end
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Updating Data Set Successful")
}
```